# Using bitfield-structs in binary de-serialization: is layout guaranteed on GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-fields

So, I'm writing a struct that's going to be used for de-serializing a binary stream of data. To get the point across, here is a cut-down version:

```c
typedef struct
{
    bool flag1 : 1;
    bool flag2 : 1;
    bool flag3 : 1;
    bool flag4 : 1;
    uint32_t reserved : 28;
} frame_flags_t;

typedef struct
{
    /* Every frame starts with a magic value. */
    uint32_t magic;

    frame_flags_t flags;

    uint8_t reserved_1;
    
    /* A bunch of other things */

    uint32_t crc;
} frame_t;
```

My question is, if do the following:

```c
frame_t f;

memcpy(&f, raw_data_p, sizeof(frame_t));
```

Am I guaranteed that `f.flags.flag1` is really the first bit (after the `magic` member, assuming a neatly packed struct (which it is))? And that `.flags2` will be the one following that, and etc?

From what I understand the C and C++ standards don't guarantee this. Does GCC?

Comment: Apparently it is unspecified behavior. I'd stay clear out of using it even if GCC doesn't pad this struct... https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field

Comment: You have multiple issues there: 1) Bitfields have implementation defined behaviour. They don't need to be placed in a way you might expect. And you seem to assume that struct to be 32 bits large. When using different types, you should not rely on that. 2) Your struct `frame_t` could contain some padding bytes. 3) The endianess of your machine does not need to match endianess of data in your stream.

Comment: I believe you'll get consistent results if you limit yourself to only little-endian architectures (or only big-endian architectures, if you can find any).  I also believe that using raw structs for de/serialization is a terrible idea, but it's a very popular technique, so don't let me stop you. :-)

Comment: Using bit-fields, or even plain structures for serialization is a bad idea. But since you asked, [this GCC manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation) says that it is basically *"Determined by ABI."*.

Comment: @user694733 what do you suggest instead of de-serialization? memcpying each member at a time? (and using `.flag1 = rawmemory & bitmask;` for the bitfields)?

Comment: Yes, `memcpy` or combine bytes to larger units with bit shifting and OR masking. Latter has advantage of not being host endianness dependent. These manual methods also allow for frames with variable length or optional fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I guaranteed that `f.flags.flag1` is really the first bit (after the `magic` member, assuming a neatly packed struct (which it is))?

The C language does not guarantee that, no.

> And that `.flags2` will be the one following that, and etc?

The C language *does* require that consecutive bitfields assigned to the same addressable storage unit be laid out without gaps between them.  That is likely to mean that the flags end up occupying adjacent bits in the same byte, but it does not *have* to mean that.

> From what I understand the C and C++ standards don't guarantee this. Does GCC?

No.  Structure layout rules are a characteristic of an *application binary interface* (ABI), which is a property of operating system + hardware combinations.  For example, there is an ABI for Linux running on x86_64, a different one for Linux running on 32-bit x86, and still different ones for Windows running on those platforms.  GCC supports a wide variety of ABIs, and it lays out structures according to the rules of the target ABI.  It cannot make any blanket guarantees about details of structure layout.

For example, the relevant **ABI for Linux / x86_64** is https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf.  With respect to bitfield layout, it says:

> Bit-fields obey the same size and alignment rules as other structure
> and union members.
>
> Also:
>
> - bit-fields are allocated from right to left
> - bit-fields must be contained in a storage unit appropriate for its declared type
> - bit-fields may share a storage unit with other struct / union members

That's actually not altogether consistent, but the way it's interpreted for your `frame_flags_t` is that:

- the structure has size 4, consisting of a single "addressible storage unit" of that size into which all the bitfields are packed
- `flag1` uses the least-significant bit
- `flag2` uses the second-least-significant bit
- `flag3` uses the third-least-significant bit
- `flag4` uses the fourth-least-significant bit

Furthermore, the overall `frame_t` structure has a 4-byte alignment requirement on Linux / x86_64, and it will be laid out with the minimum padding required to align all members. On such a machine, therefore, there will be no padding between the `magic` member and the `flags` member.  x86_64 is little-endian, so that will indeed put the flag bits in the first byte following `magic` **on Linux / x86_64**.

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile I was pointed to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html which confirms "The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (C90 6.5.2.1, C99 and C11 6.7.2.1). -> Determined by ABI.".

Comment: Also, this is for ARM v7, but I get the idea from the X86 example.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  There are at least two messages here, @RuiOliveira.  One is that you can consult the appropriate ABI to obtain this kind of detail about a given build.  The second is that if you want to write *portable* software then you will not rely on structure layout details, especially when it comes to bitfields.

Comment: Yes. This is for a platform-specific application running on a single device. But the message is noted for anything portable.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, this is for ARM v7,

On this target you can safely use the bitfields and their behaviour is clearly specified by ABI.